# Auto Generate Simple Products Error

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Trying to setup a Configurable Product.

Up to my fifth listing for different colours in the one listing. The latest listing which has variations of Storage Size;`(16GB, 32GB, 64GB)` and Colour; `(Black, White, Pink, Merlot Red, Rose Gold Black, Rose Gold White)`

I get this error when clicking on "
Generate combinations of Simple Products" button;

> Auto Generate Simple Products SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1061-1060' for key
>   'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID', query was:
>   INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_link` (`product_id`,`parent_id`)
>   VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?),
>   (?, ?), (?, ?)

Worked with the other four listings, but they had much smaller sizes and colours. Anybody know anything I can do?

This is from an addon called [Simple Products Generator](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-products-generator.html)

EDIT: It seems to be any variation of sizes/colours, it will not write into the database anymore I'm guessing? I've tried one size & one colour and the same error comes up.

EDIT2: It managed to pass the "Processing" with One colour 3 sizes, but after it finishes and you click "Close" the drop down menu products it creates do not show up on the Associated Products page. But if I have a look into Manage Products the pages are definitely created. Just not linked to the Original Listing.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0):

I pulled my hair out for hours over this, not really answered but I uninstalled the Addon and just used the "custom options" and added the colours/sizes/variations myself using that.

Addon might be buggy on later version of Magento 1.9+